# I recently purchased a wok from goodwill however I cannot figure out if it is carbon or stainless steel

Tags: pan, seasoning-pans, stainless-steel, wok, carbon-steel

I tested the wok with magnets and they stick, so aluminum is ruled out. It definitely is not cast iron, and it has a small “china” text etched into the small handle connector. Not a complete round bottom but it is already seasoned, I think. I may still season it though, I'm planning to use it on a large fireplace because I do not have a gas stove as well, so finding out the material may help.

[image]

Comment: For practical purposes the only magnetic metal is ferritic ( and martensitic) steels, AKA ordinary steel. That includes Ferritic stainless steels , usually 13 % chrome  and cutlery grades 420, 440 , etc.

Comment: Looks like steel with a nonstick coating to me, but it COULD be preseasoned carbon steel. @Tetsujin's test will help you tell which.  If it's nonstick, I wouldn't use it in a fireplace.

Comment: Mild steel is not the same thing as carbon steel.

Comment: Tetsujin: that is absolutely false.  I'm an artist blacksmith.  "carbon steel", as used in cookware (including pans and knives) is what's called "high carbon steel", containing .7 to 2% carbon. That high carbon content gives it its hardness and rigidity.  Mild steel is low-carbon and low-nickel, is quite soft, and and you would never use it for cookware because it would leach metal flavor into the food as well as getting dented and scratched to heck.

Comment: Thank you. I determined it was carbon steel. Although I accidentally burned the secondary handle, it is good.